# Magento 2 how to change order increment id?

Tags: magento2.3, sales-order, increment-id

I just migrate data from **magento 1 to magento 2**

Magento 1 order id start with `10000001` and magento 2 order id start with `00000001`

So we need order id start from `100000062` in magento 2 **(because in magento 1 last order id is 100000061)**

i checked a stackexchange but they all start from they only suggest change default order id.

Comment: You can check SQL approach @sumeet bajaj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open **phpmyadmin** and Open `sequence_order_1` Table

Go to the Operations tab of the `sequence_order_1` table, and find the field called **AUTO_INCREMENT** in the **"Table options"** box.

[image]

Comment: i checked in my local system entity_id start with 100(because for testing purpose) then sales_order entity_id column start from 100 and when i checked in sales_order_grid entity_id start from 100 but increment id still old please check screenshot - https://prnt.sc/o9wcla

Comment: Go to the Operations tab of the sequence_order_1 table, and find the field called AUTO_INCREMENT in the "Table options" box.

Comment: attached screenshot please check

Comment: so i need to changed auto increment sales_order or sequence_order_1 or both ?

Comment: no if you change only increment id then change in sequence_order_1

Comment: after change sequence_order_1 check increment id change or not

Comment: wait checking in my localhost and let you know

Comment: oky buddy..... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95660/discussion-between-sumeet-bajaj-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: working or not ??

Comment: working thanks for your help and time

Comment: only change on sequence_order_1 table or both table??

Comment: only change sequence_order_1 table

Comment: ok i m edit my answer

Comment: thnk q happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the database and can run MySQL queries, You can use update the increment id via SQL:

```
-- Edit Store-Id & New Order Increment Id
SET @STORE_ID         = 2;
SET @NEW_INC_ID       = 100000062;

-- Do not edit below
SET @ENTITY_TYPE_ID   := (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'order');

-- Just for checking
SET @LAST_INC_ID      := (SELECT increment_last_id FROM eav_entity_store WHERE entity_type_id = @ENTITY_TYPE_ID AND store_id = @STORE_ID AND increment_prefix = @STORE_ID);

-- Update first eav_entity_store table
UPDATE eav_entity_store SET increment_last_id = @NEW_INC_ID WHERE entity_type_id = @ENTITY_TYPE_ID AND store_id = @STORE_ID AND increment_prefix = @STORE_ID;

-- Update sequence_order_{store-id} table
SET @ORDER_SEQUENCE_TABLE := CONTACT('sequence_order_', @STORE_ID);
SET @SQL := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', @ORDER_SEQUENCE_TABLE, ' AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @NEW_INC_ID);
PREPARE STMT FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE STMT;
```