# How to set Magento 2 to start a at higher Order number?

Tags: orders

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

We migrated from Magento 1.9.4 with data and settings using the Magento Migration Tool except for Orders (we did not migrate orders). Now the order numbers start from 000000001. I believe this may cause problems because we accept payments via PayPal.

- *How to check what Order numbers would PayPal be OK with?*
- **How to set Magento to start at a higher Order number?**
- **What number would you recommend to set this to?**

Comment: For questions 1 & 3 you want higher than what has already been used. Only you know the answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

[Magento 2 how to change order increment id?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280574/magento-2-how-to-change-order-increment-id)

Have a look at this answer hope this helps.
accept answer if helps

Open **phpmyadmin** and Open `sequence_order_1` Table

Go to the Operations tab of the `sequence_order_1` table, and find the field called **AUTO_INCREMENT** in the **"Table options"** box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I will definitely accept this as the answer as it worked for me. Quick question - if I need to do the same for the other websites/stores/storefronts - how would I do that? I have 3 websites running on 3 different domains on the same Magento install (and database). Thanks.

Comment: sorry no idea right now for that